# packaging the mutiple python packages for dockrfile

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have multiple python packages to be installed at the run time of the docker image in fargate task.

my docker file looks like.

---

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

FROM python:3.7

RUN pip install boto3

RUN pip install nltk

RUN pip install pillow

RUN pip install tika

RUN pip install pathlib
```

How do i optimize the above dockerfile to initialise the fargate task in less time.

Comment: you save some time with installing all package at once with `pip install boto3 nltk pillow tika pathlib`. I don't think you need two "FROM" instructions in this case.  When you are saying "at the run time" do you mean "at build time"? (run time would be when you actually start the dockercontainer, but in the example you provide, you show commands that are run at build time of the image). Does it make a difference that this is a fargate task or would any solution also apply to a regular docker installation?

Comment: you might also consider putting all the packages into a `requirements.txt` file. you could do `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to create the file, COPY it into the container and install it with `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: yes, you can use a single requirement.txt as @badger0053 mentioned. to increase the initializing time, you can use a smaller docker image. You can also increase the CPU and memory spec of your tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Docker and AWS Fargate are not the same. Fargate is an orchestration engine to deploy the docker images. The question is not related to the `fargate` task at all. When a fargate service starts, it pulls a docker image and runs it. The image creation is not a part of Fargate.

If you are asking the process of containerizing, and you have specific versions of libraries. Create a base image that already have the libs. So instead of using the base `ubuntu:16.04` and installing the required libs, just have an image with `ubuntu:16.04` + `all the required libs`. And used it as something like below in your `Dockerfile`

`FROM yourrepo/ubuntu:16.04`